# Doubts Regarding Evaluation of Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, complex-integration

I was encountered following example.In that I do not understand Last part.[image]

[image]

I do not understand following .
Why such adjustment has been done?[image]
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: The adjustment has been done because it's clear that as $\varepsilon\to0$ the integral $\int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}}E(z)dz\to0$.  Therefore, we can drop it out and concentrate on the part that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E(z)=-\left(\dfrac{1}{2!}+\dfrac{iz}{3!}+\dfrac{(iz)^2}{4!}+\cdots\right)$$
then
$$|E(z)|\leq\dfrac{1}{2!}+\dfrac{|z|}{3!}+\dfrac{|z|^2}{4!}+\cdots\to\dfrac12$$
as $z\to0$.